# Docker build fails at npm install

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, npm

Hi im trying to use docker with an Angular application but it fails at npm install while "locally" when I run npm install I don't get those dependency errors/warnings.

Here is the error log from docker build:

```
 > [node 4/6] RUN npm install:
#12 9.943 npm notice
#12 9.943 npm notice New patch version of npm available! 7.5.1 -> 7.5.2
#12 9.944 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.5.2>
#12 9.944 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@7.5.2` to update!
#12 9.944 npm notice
#12 9.950 npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
#12 9.956 npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
#12 9.956 npm ERR!
#12 9.956 npm ERR! While resolving: hotel-manager@0.0.0
#12 9.956 npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.1.3
#12 9.956 npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
#12 9.956 npm ERR!   dev typescript@"^4.1.3" from the root project
#12 9.957 npm ERR!   peer typescript@"~4.0.0 || ~4.1.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1101.2
#12 9.957 npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
#12 9.957 npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1101.2" from the root project
#12 9.957 npm ERR!   2 more (@angular/compiler-cli, ng-packagr)
#12 9.957 npm ERR!
#12 9.957 npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
#12 9.957 npm ERR! peer typescript@"~3.9.5" from tsickle@0.39.1
#12 9.957 npm ERR! node_modules/tsickle
#12 9.957 npm ERR!   peerOptional tsickle@"~0.39.0" from ng-packagr@11.1.3
#12 9.958 npm ERR!   node_modules/ng-packagr
#12 9.958 npm ERR!     peerOptional ng-packagr@"^11.0.0 || ^11.1.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1101.2
#12 9.958 npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
#12 9.958 npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1101.2" from the root project
#12 9.958 npm ERR!
#12 9.958 npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
#12 9.958 npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
#12 9.959 npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
#12 9.959 npm ERR!
#12 9.959 npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
#12 9.967
#12 9.967 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#12 9.967 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-02-04T09_16_48_306Z-debug.log
```

Here is the log from npm install in vscode:

```
npm WARN @angular/http@2.4.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.4.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.10 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.4.10 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.4.10 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.1 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

As I understood the optional lines are for mac users, I'm using windows 10 build 18363
I don't use any `@angular/http` but "@angular/commons/http" instead and I could not get rid of those warnings but i don`t think that could cause the error.

Here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "hotel-manager",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^11.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^11.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.1.2",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^11.1.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "ng-editable-table": "^0.3.15",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1101.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.16",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

and the nginx.prod.dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:latest as node
LABEL  author = 'Sunflame'
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build -- --prod

# Stage 2
FROM nginx:latest
VOLUME /var/cache/nginx
COPY --from=node /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY  nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

I build with the following command:

`docker build -t nginx-angular -f nginx.prod.dockerfile .`

Can you please help what did I do wrong?

Comment: Since you're sure your local version installs correctly, add a step to copy the `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: Hmm it works this way, but are you sure that it is the real solution and not a hack? :)

Comment: Have you used `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` before? It's used for precisely this reason - to lock down the dependencies used in projects. While `package.json` indicates the dependencies' versions, bear in mind that when you do a fresh install, npm will install the latest version based on whether you indicate `^ (minor and patch)` or `~ (patch)`. Therefore, the versions will not be the same as the one that you have on local.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, add a step in the docker file to copy the `package-lock.json` file over to the destination.

The reason why it works on your local machine is because `package-lock.json` tells npm exactly which versions to install. For example, `Typescript` is listed as `^4.1.3` in `package.json`. In your local machine, it could have been installed as exactly `4.1.3` (check your `package-lock.json`) file. However, in the production machine, it might have installed version `4.2.1` or something. So even though you listed `4.1.3`, it actually pulls in a higher version because of the `^` prefix, which means you are good with having higher minor and patch versions installed. Therefore, you might be expecting `4.1.3` or whatever version it is on your local machine, the production server might have installed a much newer version because it did not refer to the `package-lock.json` file that's created in your local machine.

Check out what `^` and `~` means here in this answer - [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I also found I have to use COPY package*.json then it will copy both packages.

Comment: I am unable to fix this issue even after copying package-lock.json

Comment: @AdityaGaddhyan instead of npm install, use npm ci. It will refer to the package-lock.json file to install deps

Comment: same issue @codemax. here is my docker file : ```FROM node:16-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=dev
WORKDIR /usr/checked-backend
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
ENV PATH /usr/checked-backend/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY . .
COPY ./src/common ./src/common
RUN npx tsc
CMD ["node","./build/index.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me.

1. Remove the package-lock.json file. or
2. change the step to COPY package.json ./

Answer (score -1):

Or you can delete your package-look.json it work for me.